# batch processing in azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-lake

We are planning to do batch processing on a daily basis. We generate 1 GB of CSV files every day and will manually put them into Azure Data Lake Store. I have read the Microsoft Azure documents regarding the batch processing and I have decided to use Spark as to batch processing. My question is that after we transfer the data using RDD/DF what would be the next step? how we can visualize the data? since this process is supposed to be run every day, once the  data transformation done using Spark, do we need to push the data to any kind of data store like hive hdfs or cosmos before we could visualize it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options doing this on Azure. It really depends on your requirements (e.g. number of users, needed visualizations, etc). Examples for doing it:

- Running Spark on Azure Databricks, you could use the Notebook capabilities to visualize your data
- Use HDInsight with Jupyter or Zeppelin Notebooks
- Define Spark tables on Azure Databricks and visualize them with Power BI
- Load the data with Azure Data Factory V2 to Azure SQL DB or Azure SQL Data Warehouse and visualize it with Power BI.
- For Time-Series-Data you could push the data via Spark to Azure EventHubs (see Example notebook with Eventhubs Sink in the following [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/structured-streaming/streaming-event-hubs.html)) and consume it via Azure Time Series Insights. If you have an EventData-Stream this could also replace your batch oriented architecture in the future. Parquet files will be used by Azure Time Series Insights as Long-term Storage (see the following [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/propel-your-iot-platform-to-the-cloud-with-azure-time-series-insights/)). For Spark also have a look at [Time Series Package](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/README.md) which adds some time series capabilities to spark.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, we receive a time series meter data from many devices :
Phase Time (UTC) Sensor Voltage (Vrms) Current (Arms) Real Power (kW) Reactive Power (kVAr) 
A 30/11/2017 0:00 1 242.049 94.7869 22.6874 3.4158          
B 30/11/2017 0:00 2 242.648 58.2347 13.9256 2.39754 
C 30/11/2017 0:00 3 243.448 74.8243 17.0897 6.30549 
A 30/11/2017 0:10 1 241.358 93.3049 22.2974 3.15765

This is how our data looks like, for now, we are considering batch processing which includes 1 GB CSV files every day, but later on, we have implement real time processing too.

Comment: My first question is what Power BI offers over Jupyter or Zeppelin Notebooks visualization, and since it is a time series , should we use time series database like influx? or column-oriented file format like parquet to store the data before or after processing with spark?